# Moment.js: "TypeError: momentRange.range" when using with moment-range

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone, moment-range

I have problem using all 3 of the packages together. I define them like this:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var momentRange = require('moment-range');
```

And when I want to use the moment-range functions, I'm trying to call it like this:

```
var range1 = momentRange.range(moment("string1"), moment("string2"));
```

And I'm getting error: `TypeError: momentRange.range is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, you are supposed to use the `moment-range` library to first *extend* the core `moment` library itself, then use `moment.range` because the `moment-range` package adds additional functions to the `moment` object:

```
var momentRange = require('moment-range');
momentRange.extendMoment(moment);

moment.range(moment(…), moment(…)); // Now usable
```

Specifically, in [their documentation](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#node--npm):

> #### CommonJS:
>
> ```
> const Moment = require('moment');
> const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
>
> const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);
> ```

Comment: So, do I need to do this in every file I want to use `range` or just at index file?